# Swift: My generic subclass doesn't inherit initializers

Tags: swift, generics, inheritance, initialization, initializer

I thought both these classes conformed to the rules of inherited initializers:

```
class Butt1 : UIButton {}
class Butt2<T> : UIButton {}

let butt1 = Butt1() // ok
let butt2 = Butt2<Void>() // error: no accessible initializer
```

The docs say:

> As mentioned above, subclasses do not inherit their superclass 
>   initializers by default. However, superclass initializers are
>   automatically inherited if certain conditions are met. In practice,
>   this means that you do not need to write initializer overrides in many
>   common scenarios, and can inherit your superclass initializers with
>   minimal effort whenever it is safe to do so.
>
> Assuming that you provide default values for any new properties you
>   introduce in a subclass, the following two rules apply:
>
> **Rule 1** If your subclass doesn’t define any designated initializers, it
>   automatically inherits all of its superclass designated initializers.
>
> **Rule 2** If your subclass provides an implementation of all of its
>   superclass designated initializers—either by inheriting them as per
>   rule 1, or by providing a custom implementation as part of its
>   definition—then it automatically inherits all of the superclass
>   convenience initializers.

In the case of `Butt2` the compiler doesn't think it's "safe to do so", but why isn't it safe?

Comment: We should also note that replacing `UIButton` with `Root` (defined as `class Root {}`) does solve the compiler error.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to test that.